# Find difference between two time strings in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have two times in the string format HHMM and I want to find the difference in minutes.

I've tried the below but I'm getting the following error:

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'

```
import datetime  

a = "0628"
b = "0728"

aSep = a[:2] + ':' + a[2:]
bSep = b[:2] + ':' + b[2:]

timeA = datetime.datetime.strptime(aSep, '%H:%M').time()
timeB = datetime.datetime.strptime(bSep, '%H:%M').time()

diff = timeB -timeA
print diff
```

Comment: `time` objects don't support subtraction. If you took off `.time()`, you would have two `datetime` objects, which **do** support subtraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import datetime  

a = "0628"
b = "0728"

timeA  = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, "%H%M")
timeB  = datetime.datetime.strptime(b, "%H%M")

print((timeB-timeA).total_seconds())
print(((timeB-timeA).total_seconds()/60.0))
```

**Output:**

```
3600.0
60.0
```

Comment: *"..I want to find the difference in **minutes**."*. +1 nevertheless

Comment: Can I divide this through by 60 to get minutes?

Comment: @GrayRidley If you don't mind decimals in your output (e.g., `12.31564` min), sure. Otherwise, use `//` and you will be at max +- a min off.